# Proving tangent to graph at P is perpendicular PQ, the closest line connecting P to a point Q

Tags: calculus

The question reads:

Let $f(x)$ be a function whose graph is contained in the first quadrant but does not pass through the x-axis and let $Q = (a,0)$ . Let $P=(x_o, f(x_o))$ be the point on the graph closest to Q. Prove that the line PQ is perpendicular to the tangent line to the graph at $x_o$. ($Hint:$ Recall that the slope $m'$ of a line $L'$ perpendicular to a line $L$ of slope $m$ is $m' = \frac{-1}{m}$ .)

Edit (second attempt):

$$x\geq 0, y\geq 0 $$
$$D = \sqrt{(f(x_o)-0)^2 + (x_o - a)^2}$$
$$D' = \frac{2(f(x_o))f'(x_o) + 2(x_o-a)(1)}{2\sqrt{(f(x_o)-0)^2 + (x_o - a)^2}}$$
$$D' = 0$$
$$2(f(x_o))f'(x_o) + 2(x_o-a)(1) = 0$$
$$(x_o-a)=-(f(x_o))f'(x_o)$$
$$-\frac{(x_o-a)}{f(x_o)}=f'(x_o)$$
$$-\frac{1}{f'(x_o)} = \frac{f(x_o)}{(x_o-a)}$$

Which is the desired result.

Comment: You can make life easier for yourself by considering $D^2$. That way you'll do away with all of the roots.

Comment: Actually you need to show that the gradient of $PQ=\frac{f(x_o)}{x_o-a} = -\frac1{f'(x_o)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track but you are wrong by trying to show $D' = -\frac{1}{f'(x_o)}$. What you really need is to find $x_0$ where $D'(x_0)=0$ first and show ${f(x_0)\over x_0-a}=-\frac{1}{f'(x_o)}$.

You are also wrong when evaluating the derivative.

$$D' = \frac{2(f(x_o))f'(x_o) + 2(x_o-a)(0)}{2\sqrt{(f(x_o)-0)^2 + (x_o - a)^2}}$$

This is wrong and the correct derivative should be

$$D' = \frac{2(f(x_o))f'(x_o) + 2(x_o-a)(1)}{2\sqrt{(f(x_o)-0)^2 + (x_o - a)^2}}$$

You might be assuming $x_0$ is a constant to get the $(0)$ but that is not true. $D$ is a function over $x_0$ and you want to find the $x_0$ that minimizes $D$.

Let $D'=0$ you get $2(f(x_o))f'(x_o) + 2(x_o-a)(1)=0$ and hence ${f(x_0)\over x_0-a}=-\frac{1}{f'(x_o)}$.